# perlmod question

Tags: perl, perl-module

In the example in [perlmod/Perl Modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) there is a `BEGIN` block. I looked at some modules but none of these had a `BEGIN` block. Should I use such a `BEGIN` block when writing a module or is it dispensable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need a `BEGIN` block if you need to execute some code at *compile* time versus *run-time*.

An example: Suppose you have a module `Foo.pm` in a non-standard library directory (like `/tmp`). You know you can have perl find the module by modifying `@INC` to include `/tmp`. However, this will not work:

```
unshift(@INC, '/tmp');
use Foo;    # perl reports Foo.pm not found
```

The problem is that the `use` statement is executed at compile time whereas the `unshift` statement is executed at run time, so when perl looks for `Foo.pm`, the include path hasn't been modified (yet).

The right way to accomplish this is:

```
BEGIN { unshift(@INC, '/tmp') };
use Foo;
```

Now the `unshift` statement is executed at compile-time and before the `use Foo` statement.

The vast majority of scripts will not require `BEGIN` blocks. A lot of what you need in `BEGIN` blocks can be obtained through `use`-ing other modules. For instance, in this case we could make sure `/tmp` is in `@INC` by using the `lib.pm` module:

```
use lib '/tmp';
use Foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

A BEGIN block in a module is entirely dispensable.  You only use it if there is something that must be done by your module when it is loaded, before it is used.  There are seldom reasons to do much at that point, so there are seldom reasons to use a BEGIN block.